# Is there a way for an observable to call its error callback if a variable of invalid type is emitted?

Tags: rxjs

I want the observers error callback to be triggered if the subject somehow emit an invalid type.

There is a workaround for checking for undefined, by checking the truthy value of the returned value, but that would make the undefined value reach the `next` callback.

```js
public priceChange = new Subject<number>()

this.priceChange.subscribe({
   next: change => ..,
   error: err => ..,
})

this.priceChange.next(42)
this.priceChange.next(undefined)
this.priceChange.next('Potato')
```

I want only the valid value, i.e. 42 to be called in the `next` callback. The other values should only reach the `error` callback.

Comment: Please check pipe operators `catchError` and `throwError` [HERE](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and teak your answer according to this. to read more about `catchError` [HERE](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError)

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.priceChange.pipe(
    map(change => {
      if (typeof change !== WHATEVER YOU WANT) {
        throw 'type is not valid ......!';
      }
      return change;
    }),
    catchError(err => {
      throw 'error in source. Details: ' + err;
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(
    x => console.log(x),
    err => console.log(err)
  );
```